# pdf417 barcode scanner in IOS is not working

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, pdf417

I am developing pdf417 barcodescanner in phonegap. I tested in android mobile. Its working like a charm, but when I tested it in IOS ,I am not getting any error,but not calling pdf417scanner in IOS. I added CDVpdf417.h,CDVpdf417.m plugins and added  `<plugin name="CDVpdf417" value="CDVpdf417" />` ,

config.xml:

```
     <feature name="Pdf417Scanner">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVpdf417" />
        </feature> .
```

index.js:

```
scanButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

            var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/Pdf417Scanner");

            //cordova.plugins.pdf417Scanner.scan(
            scanner.scan(
                // Register the callback handler
                function callback(data) {

                    alert("got result " + data.data + " type " + data.type);

                    if (data.cancelled == true) {
                        resultDiv.innerHTML = "Cancelled!";
                    } else if (data.resultList && data.resultList.length > 1) {
                        // More than 1 element in results
                        resultDiv.innerHTML = data.resultList.length + " results";
                    } else {



                        resultDiv.innerHTML = "Data: " + data.data + " (raw: " + hex2a(data.raw) + ") (Type: " + data.type + ")";
                    }
                },

                // Register the errorHandler
                function errorHandler(err) {
                    alert('Error');
                },

                [ ["PDF417", "QR Code"], true ] //We want qr codes and pdf417 scanned with the beep sound on
            );
        });
```

can you tell me where I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you use plugman to install plugin? Which Phonegap version? Additional iOS project features and resources are added using plugman:  http://goo.gl/UIAq9j Do you get any error messages in NSlog?